# Setup solr to remove wikipedia markup and html

Tags: solr, wikipedia

What tokenizers factory should I use to remove wikimarkup during indexing and querying?

Answer (score 0):

[HTMLStripCharFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory) should help you remove HTML characters.